# import .sql file into a remote server from a local machine

Tags: ssh, mysql, remote, database

I've created a database in the remote machine. Currently, the database is empty and I need to import using a backup(`.sql`) file. The backup file is in my local machine, it is a `40gb` file. And the remote machine has an empty space of about `45gb`.

So, if I try to upload the backup file into the remote machine, then it will be impossible to import into the database(remote machine will be running out of space). The only possible solution looks like, pointing the server to use the location of the local machine's backup file and to import. Is there any command to work on this?

I have tried the following commands

```
bash > mysql -h hostname -u user -pPassword databasename < /Users/path/to/file/backup.sql > update.log
```

But, it returns an error saying

```
bash: no such file or directory.
```

I'm sure the file is present within my local machine.

Does any one have any idea on how to import sql file. Or is there any alternate ways to do this?

Local machine is running on `OS X`
Remote machine is `SUN OS`.
I'm using SSH to connect with remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach, but the one you tried is also right and should work:

```
cat /Users/path/to/file/backup.sql | mysql -h hostname -u user -pPassword -D databasename > update.log
```

Just in case, do you have mysql-client installed on your local machine?

Comment: cat command is used to read the file right?? Yes i have mysql-client installed in my local machine

Comment: The `cat` is not necessary ( `<   /Users/path/to/file/backup.sql  mysql .....`

Comment: @Anthon, So what does this command actually do? Is it going to open our local mysql and later connecting to server database?

Comment: I tried to execute the command it says, cannot connect to MYSQL server on 'hostname'

Comment: @GIRI I never used MySQL, I just noticed that in the command sequence baggy provided that the cat was not necessary.

Comment: I tried both the commands, none worked for me.

Comment: @GIRI `cat` is used here to read file and pass its content to mysql command. Even though it's not necessary, using it is making more obvious what does the whole sequence do.

Comment: @GIRI Since you can't connect to remote mysql, you should check your firewall on remote host - mysql uses port `3306` so make sure you can connect to that port from local machine. Also, mysql user you use must have permission to connect from remote host. You can check that when you open mysql console on remote machine and enter `SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user where user = 'YOURUSER';` If you get only one row with `localhost` in host column, your user doesn't have permission to connect and you must `GRANT` him right permissions - e.g. `GRANT ALL ON yourdb.* TO 'youruser'@'%';`

Answer (score -1):

You have to run that command in the machine where the file exists. Not on the MySQL Server.
Alternatively copy it to the MySQL server and run.

Comment: Ya, I'm running it in my machine (not on mysql server). As the sql file is a huge file and server will be running out of space if I copy and import it.